Not able to install jsonwebtoken package for authentication in nodejs

$ npm i jsonwebtoken
npm error code ETARGET
npm error notarget No matching version found for type@module.
npm error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

I am not able to install jsonwebtoken package.My npm is also of latest version. Even tried for the previous version of jsonwebtoken but nothing happened.

I was having the same issue once. This helped me:
npm cache clean --force


i did it but still not working.
i checked the cache it is clean after running npm cache clean --force
but still the same error

I found the issue. In the dependencies in package.json,
I had included "type": "module". After removing this, everything started working well.

Try deleting node_modules/ completely and try to install again everything
rm -rvf node_modules/ --> delete all node_modules
npm install  ---> install it again
npm i jsonwebtoken ---> try to install jsonwebtoken
npm i @types/jsonwebtoken---> and their types if you're using typescript
